# Получить TAG элемента listView

Tags: java, listview, tag

Добрый день. Есть ListView в котором два TextView у каждого из которых свой тег. Есть метод чтобы достать этот тэг?

Пытаюсь так `listView.getChildAt(position).getTag()` но выдаёт что то в этом роде `ListViewAdapter$ViewHolder@2c77d712`. А должен быть тег listW.

Comment: Конкретно на этот вопрос я ответа не нашёл. Но мне это нужно было, чтобы запустить какое-то действие при нажатии на одну из TextView. На это на просторах интернета я нашёл ответ. Если кому интересно: if(view.findViewById(R.id.idView1)!=null) {TODO}....if(view.findViewById(R.id.idView2)!=null) {TODO}

Comment: Если кто знает ответ на изначальный вопрос, было бы интересно узнать.